# InvalidCastException: column is null but only after implementing data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I tried implementing a data annotation into my model simply to make it [Required].

The annotation that blew it up:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name.")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string? Firstname { get; set; }
```

For some reason this works in the other models with essentially identical set up:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Message")]
[DisplayName("Message")]
public string? Message { get; set; }
```

But I did the very first block, it blew up and gave me this:

InvalidCastException: Column 'description' is null.

So its saying the column is null, but I don't know why that would be the case.

What I've tried is:

- removing the question mark on string datatype, didn't work.
- tried fiddling around with the line in question (await _context), nothing
- changing order of the model fields/attributes

The table works perfectly fine when I DON'T put a required annotation on it, but I NEED to do that as per the requirements of this particular project.

Is this a database problem? It's getting stopped at the line where it pulls from the database, I think so there could be something up with that?

It is using postgres which is not something I'm fully familiar with. I might need to contact our database guy.

I'm fairly stumped right now - if anyone needs me to elaborate a little further. Just ask and I'll share what I can.

Comment: Does the database contain nulls in the column corresponding to that `Firstname` property where it doesn;t in other columns like `Message`? Is this an EF entity or the like or is it a view model?

Comment: I'm suspecting this might be the issue also. But I don't have immediate access to the DB (the password) so I'll have to get back to you. This is a view model.

Comment: I have discord and we can meet us and try to resolve. Ricardo#1318

Comment: If you're going to chat about this issue, don't do it on Discord where the conversation will be functionally invisible to everyone else.

Comment: @jmcilhinney you were right - there was nulls in pre-existing entries which caused it to stumble whenever implementing [required] because it didn't know what to do with the pre-existing null values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem later and realized what was happening:

Before implementing required attribute, there was already pre-existing bad data that didn't meet the condition laid out by the model that you are putting the required attribute on - so it threw a InvalidCastException on the Index() page but didn't throw it when you removed the [required] attribute because that "bad record" theoretically met the model requirements at the time of entry before the [required] attribute.

So, if you get this error - either clear out all your old data first OR check through each existing entry in the db to make sure that whatever field you are placing a [required] attribute on actually has a valid value for all pre-existing records.

Hope this helps!

- @jmcilhinney in the comments under the main post figured it out, I think this is what he was suggesting but I just didn't understand it at the time.